# How can the "Atheism Smash" disable divine magic in a given area?

Tags: science-based, robots, balancing-magic-systems

So, saints. I ABSOLUTELY DESPISE THEM. They're the equivalent of a pay2winner or the GM's (Game Master) girl/boyfriend. They literally have Bruce Almighty backing them up! They don't earn any of their power unless being mindless <s>automatons</s> Decepticons 24/7 requires effort and not just weakness!

Magic in this setting happens through artifacts and the creation of artifacts is also considered magic to a degree, I mean, artifact creation is something anyone can do, but only mages have the right knowledge to successfully make them. Artifacts need energy and/or material components to function, except for one-use artifacts, and have to obey by the laws of physics.

Simply put, friendship ended with Vancian magic, now Made in Abyss is my best friend. Also, subarashi and SFX: loli spilling noises.

In divine magic, the saint's deity provides the artifact, as well as the power and material components to "reload" that artifact. Basically, it's like the DM throwing magic items at you when you're down.

To balance that without needing to involve other gods, I created the concept of the "Atheism Smash", an artifact-based (namely, a glove) move that "punches God out of the picture". The attack itself comes in several different magnitudes:

1. Jeffrey Smash (disables divine magic in a 200 m radius for 10 minutes; can be used four times a day)
2. Dawkins Smash (disables divine magic in a 250 m radius for 48 minutes; can be used: twice a day)
3. Atheist Alliance of Smash (disables divine magic in a 400 m radius for 20 minutes; can be used once a day)

Artifacts, powered and created by divine magic, lose all their charges (stored energy) upon entering the affected area. Artifacts that convert stored energy into other types (kinetic, heat, chemical, etc) and their products (i.e: the chlorine gas of an artifact that creates poisonous clouds) also experience this upon entering, but it takes some time until their energy is depleted.

Deities get their energy by taking a little bit from the pool of the energy their believers naturally produce. Basically, a deity can allocate the energy and artifact-making power of thousands into a single saint to turn them into combat nightmares.

Then it makes even less sense for the Atheism Smash to be able to not just weaken, but completely disable divine magic for up to 48 minutes. There is no collective pool to back Atheism up, the effect is produced by one overdramatized haymaker and an artifact.

**So, how can the Atheism Smash work then?**

Comment: One needs a lot of weeb culture to get a glimpse of what this question is asking

Comment: @HermantheHermaphrodite To get the references, yes; to understand the question, not really.

Comment: does it involves hairball?

Comment: @user6760 Huh? If it is a reference, make it so that I can google it.

Comment: I hate the GM's girlfriend.

Comment: @Mephistopheles A question that is wrapped in masses of inexplicable references is never easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

***The Secular Humanists strike back!***

Atheism really does end up being a religion - possibly a very powerful one. Gods are generated by the call of their worshippers. Everyone who ever doubted if gods exist, or that they deserve power, or even just wished the gods would GET LOST has worshipped Atheism and the (rather confused) deity that represents it. Since worshippers rarely take anything back from their god, he/she/it has a lot of power sitting around ready to burn (or pound). The belief in the power of Atheism fuels it, and the demonstration of that power expands the worshipper base! Godless (?) heathens uber alles!

Comment: Belief in nothing is still belief in something.

Comment: So, it taps into the collective unconscious, instead?

Comment: @Mephistopheles That's pretty close.

Comment: @TheDaleks Another way it is sometimes put: Atheism is the belief that there is no divine, it takes an Agnostic to truly not believe in anything.

Answer (score 2):

### Atheism is a form of faith

There are gods for all sorts of things: War, Love, Wisdom, Justice, etc.

Well a not so long time ago in the scale of divine beings, a god was born who needed to pick a domain, but all the good ones were already taken.  So instead of drawing from the faith of convincing people that he is real, he decided to tap into all the wasted faith that people put into convincing themselves that none of the gods are real.  It takes a lot of dedication after all to believe in nothing.  People will contradict you, they will argue with you, they will do everything they can to convince you that you are wrong; so, all that push back against these pressures to change what they believe in is the source of his power.

No mortal has the power to resist the will of a god, but gods resist each-other all the time.  To cast an Atheism Smash, you must be a saint of Atheism.  You are a paragon of non-belief that is so strong and breaks the faith of so many people that your god is willing to come to your aid to make sure you that stick around to keep "spreading the faith".

When the will of two gods clash they basically both have to commit more and more power to push the other out until one yields and decides thier saint is not worth the effort so an Atheism Smash is just your god making thier god yield, but to the caster it is the ultimate display of human achievement and the debunking of superiority of the divine.

Comment: I almost deleted this one because DWKraus beat me to the punch by 4 minutes, but I guess the OP might have a slight preference to whether a god is made by the will of man or if his gods are born then choose/are assigned domains.

Comment: You don't have to delete anything, a lot of people can have the same idea and seeing the same thing from different angles or perspectives is always usefull

Answer (score 2):

“Don’t go around believing in gods. It only encourages ‘em” - Granny Weatherwax.

Your atheists live in a world where gods and divine magic clearly exist. They accept the existence of gods and saints as a fact. They don’t have to believe in a god to accept it’s existence and more than I have to believe in The Free Market to accept that it is a thing.

This gives your atheists quite a powerful vector for attacking the gods. Because they simply treat the gods as an awkward fact of life some clever atheist mages have applied the scientific method to them (something no Believer or agnostic would ever try to do, lest they incur the wrath of a God). In doing so they unravelled part of the picture of how divine magic actually works.

The ‘Atheism Smash’ is a very specific bit of magic designed to set up an interference pattern that messes with divine magic, forcing the immense power wielded by deities to flow around the affected area rather than through it. It’s the thaumaturgic equivalent of a faraday cage, or a lightning rod: not directly opposing the power of the god (because that would be like trying to punch a thunderstorm) but instead protecting whatever is inside the bubble made by the gauntlet from divine power.

This naturally requires much less energy than actually fighting a god, and because the atheist mages objectively looked at how to make the spell work better it’s actually insanely efficient. The moniker ‘punch god out of the picture’ is actually a bit of misdirection by the clever mages that designed the system (because who doesn’t like messing with the gods).

Much like cell phones entering faraday cages this cuts off divine artefacts too. The power being routed to them by the god is instead harmlessly earthed, and the ‘stored’ energy is pulled from them as they pass into the affected area.

This does mean that when saints or highly divine objects enter an area that has been A-smashed you’ll see the excess divine power earthing itself outside. Expect rains of holy icons, unexpected resurrections and the spontaneous transmutation of nearby water sources into wine.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing on the power of denial:  say that faith has a power that is given to the gods. Therefore everybody who denied the existence of gods has their ‘faith power’ stockpiled into ‘nobody.’  So theres a lot of free energy out there for the Atheist priest, the Ur-Priest.  This smash draws on that power.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:  Saints have their deities, but you have The World -- the power of Nature

In the world, you know that the divine exists and it is fueled by the powers of their human believers.  The gods, aware that their power is based on their believers, use that belief to empower champions and/or artifacts as an investment whos return is supposed to be the increase of belief in them.  But there is something else to draw power from, and you embrace that alternate -- The World (Captial W)

The World does not care.  Call it Gaea, Mother Earth, or the consciousness of the planet, the point is that The World is not a deity, at least not in the traditional sense of an entity created by humanity.  It is the power within the planet -- the magic what suffuses it and runs through it, the plants and the animals without the capacity to believe in gods and devils, the breathtaking expances of air and the crushing depths of the ocean.

By your artifact drawing upon The World, you are in effect rejecting the man-made divine in the area by enforcing that the World's order is the one to follow in the area.  But the world wishes things to be in balance, both the unnatural miracles brought by the human gods and the alterations to nature brought by its own power.  This is why the punch only lasts a certain length of time.

Comment: ZA WARUDO, Toki wo tomare!